# Single color render background with orthographic camera

Tags: rendering, orthographic

I set up the file to render an animation with pure white background. This works fine when the camera is in perspective mode. When I switch the camera to orthographic, I do not get the white background. I just get transparent color instead of white.

I am fixing this issue with a video editor.

Is there a way to get a white background with a orthographic camera?

Edit: With the camera in perspective mode the background is still transparent. In the render properties I checked the Transparent checkbox in the Film group, then I changed the View Transform from Filmic to Standard in the Color Management group, In compositing I added a Alpha Over node between the Render Layers node and the Composite Node, then I changed the Premul from 0 to 1.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your .blend file and several screenshots of your setup. Users cannot help unless we have sample data as to your render settings, camera settings, etc. Go to [Blend-Exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/) and follow the instructions to attach your .blend file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was wrong in the file's configuration.
I created a new file, imported the objects, setup the background color, and the problem was solved.
Thanks.